# Get value of object in Javascript to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

I want show data in select drop down with jquery ajax. This my code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".inventaris").on('change',function(e) {
      console.log(e);
      var cat_id = e.target.value;

      $.get('/get-id/' + cat_id , function(data){           

        $.each(data, function(index, obj){
          console.log(obj);
        });
      });
    });
});
```

The result is :

```
[{id: 1, tgl_pinjam: "2018-06-10"},{id: 2, tgl_pinjam: "2018-06-11"}]
```

How to get?

```
["2018-06-10","2018-06-11"]
```

Comment: Why do you need that array just to show in dropdown and not iterate original?

Comment: I want to get data from database and then disable specific date datepicker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
let arr = [{id: 1, tgl_pinjam: "2018-06-10"},{id: 2, tgl_pinjam: "2018-06-11"}];
let result = arr.map(({tgl_pinjam}) => tgl_pinjam);
console.log(result);
```